# How to make flexible sized buttons in Relativelayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, horizontalscrollview, buttonbar

I have a `RelativeLayout` styled as a `ButtonBar` and contained in a `HorizontalScrollView`, this layout is a ssigned to a fixed height in order to be controlled but that make it looks giant in small screen devices,

for ex, in a **10'** device:

[image]

And in a **3.7'** device:

[image]

And here's my **XML** code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tool"
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id= "@+id/buttobbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
        android:background="@drawable/released" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Main"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:text="@string/main"/>

        <View 
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Main"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:background="@drawable/separators"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/HomeView"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Main"
            android:text="@string/homeview" />

         <View 
            android:id="@+id/separator"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/HomeView"
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:background="@drawable/separators"/>

          .
          .
          . <!-- after 7 other buttons separated with views --!>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding weight would be a best option:
Try this:

```
android:weightSum="1"
```

and divide this weight sum to the butons as follows:

```
android:layout_weight=0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

take linear layout at the place of relative layout and u dont have to give absolute value of  layout_width just use  android:layout_weight and give weight to all button
from this it will automatically  adjust on all screen whatever it will be 
 i think it will help u

Answer (score 0):

Assign weight to the layout(Linear layout) by just writing the following code:

```
 android:weightSum="1"(can vary,according to your requirement)
```

and divide this weight sum to the butons as follows:

`android:layout_weight=0.5`

Comment: and the width and height ?

Comment: android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: this width and height is to be set in linear layout